# How can I make the DefaultTrackableEventHandler script to check if the randomly selected game object is same as the game object shown to the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

This is the script that gets a randomly selected object from an array of game objects:

```
public GameObject[] models;
       GameObject currentPoint;
       int index;
 public AudioSource correct;
 public AudioSource notcorrect;

 void Start()
 {
     models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("numbers");
     index = Random.Range (0, models.Length);
     currentPoint = models[index];
     print (currentPoint.name);
     models [index].GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayDelayed(2);
     }
```

So now it gets a random game object and plays it's relevant AudioClip (for ex number 5), and now in the DefaultTrackableEventHandler i need to check if the number that is shown to the camera is equal to the number that was randomly selected.

I am posting the DefaultTrackableEventHandler script below:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Vuforia
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
    /// </summary>
    public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour,
    ITrackableEventHandler
    {
        #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

        private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

        #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES



        #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

        void Start()
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
            if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            {
                mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
            }
        }

        #endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS



        #region PUBLIC_METHODS
        public GameObject show;
        public GameObject hide;
        /// <summary>
        /// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
        /// tracking state changes.
        /// </summary>
        public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
            TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
            TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
        {
            if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
            {
                OnTrackingFound();
            }
            else
            {
                OnTrackingLost();
            }
        }

        #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS



        #region PRIVATE_METHODS


        private void OnTrackingFound()
        {
            show.SetActive(true);
            Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
            AudioSource[] audiocomponents  = GetComponentsInChildren<AudioSource>(true);
            // Enable rendering:
            foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = true;
            }


            // Enable colliders:
            foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = true;
            }

            //Enable AudioSource 
            foreach (AudioSource component in audiocomponents)
            {
                component.enabled = true;
            }

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
        }


        private void OnTrackingLost()
        {
            hide.SetActive(true);
            Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
            Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
            AudioSource[] audiocomponents  = GetComponentsInChildren<AudioSource>(true);
            // Disable rendering:
            foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }

            // Disable colliders:
            foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }
            //Disable AudioSource
            foreach (AudioSource component in audiocomponents)
            {
                component.enabled = false;
            }

            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
        }

        #endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS
    }
}
```

Please help me !!

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia works with data sets containing trackable source, so let's say you have 5 objects and they represent numbers from 1 to 5, you need to have five trackables in your data sets. Those are created on the Vuforia portal.

Then, you pick a game object, this game object should be related to a trackable. You can define the names to match, then you can do:

```
StateManager sm = TrackerManager.Instance.GetStateManager ();
// This gets all the trackable currently tracked
// so if you are looking at 3 and 5 it will contain both
IEnumerable<TrackableBehaviour> activeTrackables = sm.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours ();
 
foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in activeTrackables) {
    // As you iterate, you compare with current game object name
    // if you have 3 and 5 and target object is 5 then you get a match.
    if( tb.TrackableName == currentObject.name) { }
}
```

Comment: What is sm in sm.GetActiveTrackableBehaviours() how can i call the GetActiveTrackableBehaviour function ?

The code you posted is supposed to be in the DefaultTrackableEventHandler or in the Quiz.cs (the script that gets a random game object and plays its audioclip) ?

Comment: I added the missing line. This goes wherever you want to check. The first line (that I added) is a singleton reference call, so it can be done from any script. So most likely a relevant one like Quiz.cs.

Comment: I am getting this error: 
A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property `Quiz.sm'

I added the code to the Quiz.cs script

Comment: Nevermind I fixed this error. I just moved the initialization into Start() function

Comment: I added your code to the Quiz.cs but when I show the ImageTarget to the camera it doesn't play correct or not correct AudioClips based on that if the target shown is same as the randomly selected object. I am posting the code below :

Comment: void Start()
 {
     models = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("numbers");
     index = Random.Range (0, models.Length);
     currentPoint = models[index];
     print (currentPoint.name);
     models [index].GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayDelayed(2);
    foreach (TrackableBehaviour tb in activeTrackables) 
{
   if( tb.TrackableName == currentPoint.name) 
   { 
        correct.Play();
    }
   else 
     {
      notcorrect.Play();
      }    
 }

Comment: Your code is in the Start so it is only run once, it needs to be called either on Update on when you get a OnTrackingFound event.

Comment: I added the Quiz.cs script in the DefaultTrackableEventHandler 's OnTrackingFound function and i get this error : 

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Can you help me here ?

Comment: You need to debug what is null. The error should indicate what line makes it happen.